# Requesting direction for loading my file in chunks (Only needing advice)

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, memory-mapped-files, chunks

I've been working for the last few days on a method to compress 144 million tile representation for my xna game down to a very small size when saved. Having managed to pull that off I now find myself stumped on how to go about getting them back from the file in chunks.

In the file I have.

1. An integer (it gets compressed to bytes using the 7BitEncodedInt method)
2. A byte

The compressed integer represents the number of tiles and the byte that follows determines what type the tiles are. This is all well and good and works really well. Most importantly it shrinks the file size down to just 50mb on average.

The problem is that I am currently reading back the entire file.
From the file I'm getting this.

1. The index value of each tile (just a basic iteration as I grab the tiles)
2. The type for each tile as a byte value
3. A byte value representing a texture for that tile (this is hard to explain but its necessary on a per tile basis)

The end result of all this is that I'm managing to save the file and only use about 50mb. But by loading the whole thing back in it expands out to nearly 1.5gigs on the ram. I can't really afford to sacrifice anymore tile info. so I need a way to only load portions of the map based on the player location. The goal is to be around the 100-200mb range

I have been looking at memory mapping the file, using quadtrees, pretty much anything I could find for loading files in chunks. While these options all seem pretty good I'm not sure which is best or if given the situation there may be another even better one. The other problem with all this is that these solutions all seem very involved (especially since this is my first time using them) and while I'm not against devoting myself to some lengthy coding I'd like to know that its gonna do what I need it to before hand.

My question is, given how I have to process the file as I pull it in and the fact that it needs to be done based on the players location what would be the best way to do this ? I'm just looking for some direction here. Code is always welcome but not required.

Comment: On top of my head, jst see if u can optimize the data which ur storing on to the file and da data which u wish to transfer. Break it in chunks and send whats needed only. For network trasnfer, send which has changed and keep mostly on local machine itself. Sorry if this isnt answer ur looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have fixed length variables in your Tile class and implement something like such:

This is an example of a collection class (People) that can get a value based on index from a collection that was serialised into a file.

Person is the class that is the base of the People collection.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FileStreamDatabaseTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            People.OpenCollection();
            People.Test_WillOverwriteData();
            People.CloseCollection();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        // define maxium variable sizes for serialisation
        protected static int pMaxLength_FirstName = 64;
        protected static int pMaxLength_Age = 10;
        public static int MaxObjectSize
        {
            get
            {
                // return the sum of all the maxlegnth variables to define the entire object size for serialisation
                return pMaxLength_FirstName + pMaxLength_Age;
            }
        }

        // define each object that will be serialised as follows 
        protected string pFirstName;
        public string Firstname
        {
            set
            {
                // ensure the new value is not over max variable size
                if (value.Length > pMaxLength_FirstName)
                    throw new Exception("the length of the value is to long.");

                pFirstName = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return pFirstName;
            }
        }
        protected int pAge;
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return pAge;
            }
            set
            {
                pAge = value;
            }
        }

        public byte[] Serialise()
        {
            // Output string builder
            StringBuilder Output = new StringBuilder();

            // Append firstname value
            Output.Append(Firstname);

            // Add extra spaces to end of string until max length is reached
            if (Firstname.Length < pMaxLength_FirstName)
                for (int i = Firstname.Length; i < pMaxLength_FirstName; i++)
                    Output.Append(" ");

            // Append age value as string
            Output.Append(Age.ToString());

            // Add extra spaces to end of string until max length is reached
            int AgeLength = Age.ToString().Length;
            if (AgeLength < pMaxLength_Age)
                for (int i = AgeLength; i < pMaxLength_Age; i++)
                    Output.Append(" ");

            // Return the output string as bytes using ascii encoding
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Output.ToString());
        }

        public void Deserialise(byte[] SerialisedData)
        {
            string Values = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(SerialisedData);

            pFirstName = Values.Substring(0, pMaxLength_FirstName).Trim();
            pAge = int.Parse(Values.Substring(pMaxLength_FirstName, pMaxLength_Age).Trim());
        }
    }

    public static class People
    {
        private static string tileDatasource = @"c:\test.dat";
        private static System.IO.FileStream FileStream;

        public static void OpenCollection()
        {
            FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(tileDatasource, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, System.IO.FileShare.None);
        }

        public static void CloseCollection()
        {
            FileStream.Close();
            FileStream.Dispose();
            FileStream = null;
        }

        public static void SaveCollection(Person[] People)
        {
            FileStream.SetLength(People.Length * Person.MaxObjectSize);
            FileStream.Position = 0;

            foreach (Person PersonToWrite in People)
            {
                // call serialise to get bytes
                byte[] OutputBytes = PersonToWrite.Serialise();

                // write the output buffer
                // note: this will always be the same size as each variable should 
                //       append spaces until its max size is reached
                FileStream.Write(OutputBytes, 0, OutputBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        public static Person GetValue(int Index)
        {
            // set the stream position to read the object by multiplying the requested index with the max object size
            FileStream.Position = Index * Person.MaxObjectSize;

            // read the data
            byte[] InputBytes = new byte[Person.MaxObjectSize];
            FileStream.Read(InputBytes, 0, Person.MaxObjectSize);

            // deserialise
            Person PersonToReturn = new Person();
            PersonToReturn.Deserialise(InputBytes);

            // retun the person
            return PersonToReturn;
        }

        public static void Test_WillOverwriteData()
        {
            long StartTime;
            long EndTime;
            TimeSpan TimeTaken;

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Creating 2,000,000 test people... ");
            StartTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            Person[] People = new Person[2000000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
            {
                People[i] = new Person();
                People[i].Firstname = "TestName." + i;
                People[i].Age = i;
            }
            EndTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            TimeTaken = new TimeSpan(EndTime - StartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("-> Completed in " + TimeTaken.TotalSeconds + " seconds");

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Serialising Collection to disk... ");
            StartTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            SaveCollection(People);
            EndTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            TimeTaken = new TimeSpan(EndTime - StartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("-> Completed in " + TimeTaken.TotalSeconds + " seconds");

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Redundancy Test... ");
            StartTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            bool Parsed = true;
            int FailedCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
            {
                if (GetValue(i).Age != i)
                {
                    Parsed = false;
                    FailedCount++;
                }
            }
            EndTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            TimeTaken = new TimeSpan(EndTime - StartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("-> " + (Parsed ? "PARSED" : "FAILED (" + FailedCount + " failed index's"));
            Console.WriteLine("-> Completed in " + TimeTaken.TotalSeconds + " seconds");

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Reading 10,000 index's at once... ");
            StartTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            Person[] ChunkOfPeople = new Person[10000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                ChunkOfPeople[i] = GetValue(i);
            EndTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            TimeTaken = new TimeSpan(EndTime - StartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("-> Completed in " + TimeTaken.TotalSeconds + " seconds");


            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Reading 100,000 index's at once... ");
            StartTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            ChunkOfPeople = new Person[100000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                ChunkOfPeople[i] = GetValue(i);
            EndTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            TimeTaken = new TimeSpan(EndTime - StartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("-> Completed in " + TimeTaken.TotalSeconds + " seconds");

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Reading 1,000,000 index's at once... ");
            StartTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            ChunkOfPeople = new Person[1000000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                ChunkOfPeople[i] = GetValue(i);
            EndTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            TimeTaken = new TimeSpan(EndTime - StartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("-> Completed in " + TimeTaken.TotalSeconds + " seconds");
        }
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options, not all of them may be appropriate for your particular project:

- Don't use a single file for all the data. Divide the map in smaller "rooms" and store each one in its own file. Load only the "room" the player starts in and preemptively load neighboring "rooms" and unload old ones.
- Reduce the number of tiles you need to store. Use procedural generation to create an area's layout.
  If you have a 10x10 room with the floor made of a single tile type then don't store 100 separate tiles but instead use a specific marker that says "this area has a 10x10 floor with this tile". If it's a wall then save the start and end positions and the texture type. If you have a multi-tile doodad in the middle of an open field and it's position is not relevant to the story then position it randomly in the field (and save the seed for the random number generator in the map file so next time it will appear in the same place).